# how to obtain the best approximate fraction for a real number in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I want to obtain the best approximate fraction/rational for a given real number and the specificied maximum denominator as an integer, how to do this in mathematica? Many thanks.

Comment: The convergents of a continued fraction representation give you successively better approximations of a real number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at Help for `Rationalize`. `RootApproximant` can be also useful

Answer (score 5):

[Convergents](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Convergents.html) of [continued fractions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContinuedFraction.html) offer a useful method for getting better and better fractional representations of an irrational number.  I've also found them helpful for understanding connections to other ideas by way of the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Let's use convergents to approximate pi and the square root of two.

```
ClearAll[approximate];

approximate[r_, nConvergents_: 8, precision_: 10] := 
   With[{c = Convergents[ContinuedFraction[r, nConvergents]]}, 
   TableForm[Transpose[{c, N[r - c, precision]}], 
   TableHeadings -> {None, {Row[{"approximation of ", r}], "error"}}]]
```

Here's are the first 8 convergents for pi:

```
approximate[Pi]
```

[image: approximate pi]

Here are the first 8 convergents for `Sqrt[2]`:

```
approximate[Sqrt[2]]
```

[image: approximate root 2]

The successive error terms shrink and alternate direction as convergence advances.

In `approximate`, you can optionally specify the number of convergents and precision desired.

Enjoy.

---

Here's some additional [documentation](http://search.wolfram.com/?query=continued+fraction&x=0&y=0) about continued fractions, including some lovely demonstrations.

Comment: @Qiang Li  Here is an example of convergents homing in on an irrational number. There are some interesting geometric representations of this in the Cartesian plane.  See also: [Continued fraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFraction.html)

Comment: thank you. `ContinuedFraction` is a nice approach for this problem.